# Saving to different table from DataGridView in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datagridview

I am working on `VB.net` Windows application. I have a DataGridView that is loading from different three tables. My grid view looks like this:

```
 **Make    model        color**

toyota    corolla    red

Bmw       c100      white
```

My three table  are named `Make_tbl`, `Model_tbl`,`Color_tbl`. In my windows form I have `edit` and `save` buttons

After editing anything I want to save my data. While saving the same time i want to save this data to different  three tables. How i can do this `VB.net`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code takes a MS Access DB and update data (Insert/Update/Delete) back into database from `DataGridView` on `Button1_Click`

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb  

Public Class Form1  

    Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter  
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet  

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  
        Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=|DataDirectory|\myDB.mdb")  
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1", con)  
        con.Open()  
        myDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)  

        'One CommandBuilder object is required. It automatically generates DeleteCommand,UpdateCommand and InsertCommand for DataAdapter object  
        Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(myDA)  
        myDataSet = New DataSet()  
        myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "MyTable")
        myDA.UpdateCommand = new OledbCommandBuilder(myDA).GetUpdateCommand();  
        DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("MyTable") 
        con.Close()  
        con = Nothing 
     End Sub 

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  
        Me.Validate()  
        Me.myDA.Update(Me.myDataSet.Tables("MyTable"))  
        Me.myDataSet.AcceptChanges()  
    End Sub 

End Class
```

Comment: sir,,i will  check and let u know

Comment: No worries. Please let us know

Comment: in load event i am not getting DefaultView  ..i want to load my table data to datagrid view

Comment: Try it by removing `.DefaultView`  .This instruction `DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("MyTable")` is just what populates the `DataGridView` from your table

Comment: ok,,now data grid view loading correct,,but while clicking update button, i am getting error like this:Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Comment: sir am using sqldataadapter,,but i havnt find any sqldbcommandbuilder

Comment: Yes. I've added `myDA.UpdateCommand = new OledbCommandBuilder(myDA).GetUpdateCommand();` to get it working. For SQLClient it is  `SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder`

Comment: You are very welcome :) Please upvote too if you found this answer useful.